# OpenSSH connection doent display Path or Name

Tags: linux, path, openssh, ubuntu-12.10

I recently re-installed a Ubuntu server (12.10) and I happened to have a minor issue with OpenSSH.

Once I created some new Accounts and logged into those the terminal always replys with 
**"$"**. 
Contrary to the root account, which usually prompts with 
**"Name@Server Path:"**.

So, how exactly did I disable the path and name displaying for normal accounts? I'd like to have it back.

Comment: This has nothing to do with openssh, it has everything to do with the shell/profile that the accounts were created with.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Either Superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason for this happening is that the shell profile for the new users doesn't have any settings to adjust the shell prompt; plus it also depends on the shell that is configured for the user.

when I do:

```
useradd -m freddy
```

Then `su - freddy`, I get the prompt

```
$
```

and the ps listing:

```
$ ps
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
7258 pts/28   00:00:00 su
7266 pts/28   00:00:00 sh
7300 pts/28   00:00:00 ps
```

i.e. not using bash.

if we add the user with the `bash` shell,

```
userdel -r freddy
useradd -m -s /bin/bash freddy
su - freddy
```

we get the prompt:

```
freddy@host:~$
```

If you want to modify the login shell of the user accounts so that they will have a prompt, then you can do:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash <account name>
```

for each of the accounts.

Again, all the `useradd`, `userdel` and `usermod` commands are performed as `root`!

Comment: Using `chsh` a user can change its shell without having root privileges.

Comment: @user1761295 You should mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem, so others with the same problem can use it :).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not related to OpenSSH. The shell prompt is based on the PS1 environment variable. If you want to reset your shell prompt to "Name@Server Path:" add below lines in .bashrc or .bash_profile or .profile

```
   PS1="\u@\h:\w"
```

For more ways of setting (colourful) prompts refer [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/)